# Symfony 1.4 extend model error

Tags: model, symfony-1.4, extend

After read and re-read **Symfony's 1.4** doc and research enough in Google, I decided ask about this here.
I have a model called "`ot`" and I want to have a method `getUnreadMsg()` to get some specific data.

This is the class:

```
class ot extends Baseot {

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->getNombre();
    }

    public function getNumberOfUnreadMsgs() {
        $mensajes = Doctrine_Core::getTable('mensaje')
                ->createQuery('m')
                ->where('m.ots_id=' . $this->getId())
                ->andWhere('m.estado=0')
                ->orderBy('m.created_at DESC')
                ->execute();
        return count($mensajes);

    }
}
```

And this how I used it in the view layer:

```
<?php foreach ($ots as $ot): ?>
  ....
  <?php echo $ot->getNumberOfUnreadMsgs();   ?>
  ....
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Unknown record property / related component "number_of_unread_msgs" on "ot"
```

Comment: It sounds like it's overloading with a __get() magic method, where any getter call will try to look for a corresponding property, e.g. getFirstName() looks for a property 'first_name'. In this case it's trying to find 'number_of_unread_msgs".
My first inclination would be to think that the ot object in your foreach loop is not the same as the ot object in your model.
What does var_dump($ot) in the foreach loop show?

Comment: When I do var_dump the browser die. I get a blank page and firebug show me this error: "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."

Comment: If you can't do a var_dump() it's going to make it very difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code cannot found that method for some reason.

One thing I've noticed is the case is not right. It should be Ot not ot. Not sure if that's causing the issue but that's definitely wrong. In your confif/doctrine/ot.yml change the first line to Ot and rebuild your model.

Make the necessary updates in your code. It should work.

Comment: Thank you, yes case of the model is wrong. This cause too many issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to' renane your function with a name that don't starts with a "get".
It seems that it's going to search for a "number_of_unread_msgs" property...